# UnsatisfiedLinkError while accessing a Native method

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am using eclipse and getting the below error when I try to access a native method from a `ExtractImage.dll` file-

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: getVertices
    at com.coimp.application.ExtractImage.getVertices(Native Method)
```

I have added the dll to below paths -

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_10\bin;
. //current workspace
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
```

and I have used this method to load the library -

```
System.loadLibrary("ExtractImage");
```

Also tried with -

> System.load("c:\ExtractImage.dll");

Adding the .dll file to NativeLibrary path

The same code works on my web application.

Geeks, any guesses to fix this problem ?
Thanks for upcoming support.

Comment: Does your DLL depend on other DLLs? Use dumpbin /imports to see.

Comment: thanks @bmargulies for replying. I found the solution. Actually the called java class was in other package and Cpp class was refering to a class in some other package.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Run Configuration..." options in the "Arguments" tab specify in "VM Arguments" "-Djava.librar.path=YOUR_DIR_TO_DLL"

If the library has dependencies with other DLLs not present in the PATH, you should also include those directories (separated by ;)

**Update**
If that fails too you can modifiy PATH environment variable (in tab "Environment"). I would recommend you that you edit the variable (adding your directories) an leave the option "Append  environment to native environment" selected (radio buttons at bottom).

Comment: thanx for replying. I tried your trick and printed the path as well to check if it has taken the right path with -System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));and yes it has taken the path correctly. But still getting the same error in call to the Native Method.

Comment: The OP's exception is not the one you get on failing to load a library, which would be "no ExtractImage in java.library.path".